# How can I load input data from a file in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I defined a `aws_cloudwatch_event_target` in terraform to fire an event to lambda from `cloudwatch`. The `input` field is the event parameter for example:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "data" {
  rule      = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.scheduler.name}"
  target_id = "finance_producer_cloudwatch"
  arn       = "${aws_lambda_function.finance_data_producer.arn}"
  input     = "{\"test\": [\"111\"]}"
}
```

I wonder how I can load the `input` json data from an external file.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

The answer here depends on a few different questions:

- Is this file a static part of your configuration, checked in to version control alongside your `.tf` files, or is it dynamically generated as part of the apply process?
- Do you want to use the file contents literally, or do you need to substitute values into it from elsewhere in the Terraform configuration?

These two questions form a matrix of four different answers:

```
             |  Literal Content            Include Values from Elsewhere
-------------|----------------------------------------------------------
Static File  |  file(...) function         templatefile(...) function
Dynamic File |  local_file data source     template_file data source
```

I'll describe each of these four options in more detail below.

A common theme in all of these examples will be references to `path.module`, which evaluates to the path where the current module is loaded from. Another way to think about that is that it is the directory containing the current `.tf` file. Accessing files in other directories is *allowed*, but in most cases it's appropriate to keep things self-contained in your module by keeping the data files and the configuration files together.

Terraform strings are sequences of unicode characters, so Terraform can only read files containing valid UTF-8 encoded text. For JSON that's no problem, but worth keeping in mind for other file formats that might not conventionally be UTF-8 encoded.

## The `file` function

[The `file` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html) reads the literal content of a file from disk as part of the initial evaluation of the configuration. The content of the file is treated as if it were a literal string value for validation purposes, and so the file *must* exist on disk (and usually, in your version control) as a static part of your configuration, as opposed to being generated dynamically during `terraform apply`.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "data" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.scheduler.name
  target_id = "finance_producer_cloudwatch"
  arn       = aws_lambda_function.finance_data_producer.arn
  input     = file("${path.module}/input.json")
}
```

This is the most common and simplest option. If the `file` function is sufficient for your needs then it's the best option to use as a default choice.

## The `templatefile` function

[The `templatefile` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) is similar to the `file` function, but rather than just returning the file contents literally it instead parses the file contents as [a string template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-templates) and then evaluates it using a set of local variables given in its second argument. This is useful if you need to pass some data from elsewhere in the Terraform configuration, as in this example:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "data" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.scheduler.name
  target_id = "finance_producer_cloudwatch"
  arn       = aws_lambda_function.finance_data_producer.arn
  input     = templatefile("${path.module}/input.json.tmpl", {
    instance_id = aws_instance.example.id
  })
}
```

In `input.json.tmpl` you can use the Terraform template syntax to substitute that variable value:

```
{"instance_id":${jsonencode(instance_id)}}
```

In cases like this where the whole *result* is JSON, I'd suggest just generating the whole result using `jsonencode`, since then you can let Terraform worry about the JSON escaping etc and just write the data structure in Terraform's object syntax:

```
${jsonencode({
  instance_id = instance_id
})}
```

As with `file`, because `templatefile` is a function it gets evaluated during initial decoding of the configuration and its result is validated as a literal value. The template file must therefore also be a static file that is distributed as part of the configuration, rather than a dynamically-generated file.

## The `local_file` data source

[Data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/data-sources.html) are special resource types that read an existing object or compute a result, rather than creating and managing a new object. Because they are resources, they can participate in the dependency graph and can thus make use of objects (including local files) that are created by other resources in the same Terraform configuration during `terraform apply`.

[The `local_file` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/d/file.html) belongs to [the `hashicorp/local` provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/local/index.html) and is essentially the data source equivalent of the `file` function.

In the following example, I'm using `var.input_file` as a placeholder for any reference to a file path that is created by some other resource in the same configuration. In a real example, that is most likely to be a direct reference to an attribute of a resource.

```
data "local_file" "input" {
  filename = var.input_file
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "data" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.scheduler.name
  target_id = "finance_producer_cloudwatch"
  arn       = aws_lambda_function.finance_data_producer.arn
  input     = data.local_file.input.content
}
```

## The `template_file` data source

> **NOTE:** Since I originally wrote this answer, the provider where `template_file` was implemented has been declared obsolete and no longer maintained, and there is no replacement. In particular, the provider was archived prior to the release of Apple Silicon and so there is no available port for macOS on that architecture.
>
> The Terraform team does not recommend rendering of dynamically-loaded templates, because it pushes various errors that could normally be detected at plan time to be detected only during apply time instead.
>
> I've retained this content as I originally wrote it in case it's useful, but I would suggest treating this option as a last resort.

[The `template_file` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html) is the data source equivalent of the `templatefile` function. It's similar in usage to `local_file` though in this case we populate the template itself by reading it as a static file, using either the `file` function or `local_file` as described above depending on whether the template is in a static file or a dynamically-generated one, though if it were a static file we'd prefer to use the `templatefile` function and so we'll use the `local_file` data source here:

```
data "local_file" "input_template" {
  filename = var.input_template_file
}

data "template_file" "input" {
  template = data.local_file.input_template.content
  vars = {
    instance_id = aws_instance.example.id
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "data" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.scheduler.name
  target_id = "finance_producer_cloudwatch"
  arn       = aws_lambda_function.finance_data_producer.arn
  input     = data.template_file.input.rendered
}
```

The `templatefile` function was added in Terraform 0.12.0, so you may see examples elsewhere of using the `template_file` data source to render static template files. That is an old pattern, now deprecated in Terraform 0.12, because the `templatefile` function makes for a more direct and readable configuration in most cases.

One quirk of the `template_file` data source as opposed to the `templatefile` function is that the data source belongs to [the `hashicorp/template` provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/index.html) rather than to Terraform Core, and so which template features are available in it will depend on which version of the provider is installed rather than which version of Terraform CLI is installed. The `template` provider is likely to lag behind Terraform Core in terms of which template language features are available, which is another reason to prefer the `templatefile` function where possible.

## Other Possibilities

This question was specifically about reading data from a file, but for completeness I also want to note that for small JSON payloads it can sometimes be preferable to inline them directly in the configuration as a Terraform data structure and convert to JSON using [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html), like this:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "data" {
  rule      = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.scheduler.name
  target_id = "finance_producer_cloudwatch"
  arn       = aws_lambda_function.finance_data_producer.arn
  input     = jsonencode({
    instance_id = aws_instance.example.id
  })
}
```

Writing the data structure inline as a Terraform expression means that a future reader can see directly what will be sent without needing to refer to a separate file. However, if the data structure is very large and complicated then it can hurt overall readability to include it inline because it could overwhelm the other configuration in the same file.

Which option to choose will therefore depend a lot on the specific circumstances, but always worth considering whether the indirection of a separate file is the best choice for readability.

Terraform also has [a `yamlencode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/yamlencode.html) which can do similarly for YAML-formatted data structures, either directly inside a `.tf` file or in an interpolation sequence in an external template.

Comment: Excellent Answer... Thanks a lot for it

Comment: how to you load a file relative to a module that you are using? I have the file somewhere in my module directory but when I try to load it with file its not found. I think because I am using the module from anthor directory, so the used path isnt correct.

Comment: Thank you very much! The community appreciates such comprehensive answers like this one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`file()` operator](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/file.html) to pull data from an external file:

```
input = "${file("myjson.json")}"
```

Just make sure `myjson.json` exists on disk in the same directory as the rest of your Terraform files.

Comment: If it's in a module (IE, not at the root of your terraform solution) you can use `file("${path.module}/myjson.json")`.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the data template_file resource. Like so...

```
data "template_file" "my_file" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/my_file.json")}"
  vars = {
    var_to_use_in_file = "${var.my_value}"
  }
}
```

Then in your resource block....

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "data" {
  rule      = "${aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.scheduler.name}"
  target_id = "finance_producer_cloudwatch"
  arn       = "${aws_lambda_function.finance_data_producer.arn}"
  input     = "${data.template_file.my_file.rendered}"
}
```